# Output the file name of images using the views_data_export module?

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm using the https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export module to export a Views list of content as a CSV file.

The content has an image field (multiple values in it) then the CSV data show nothing for the images. I need to output the name of the image file.

I tried adding a Relationship field:  **File Usage: File** but I get duplicated row (one for each image in each node)

I need to output a CSV file, something like:

```
TITLE, IMAGES
"my dog title" , "dog-picture-1.jpg, dog-picture-2.jpg"
"my cat title" , "cat-picture-1.jpg, cat-picture-2.jpg"
```

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Rewrite the output of this field** option and add your fields like title, image1, image2.

1). In image1 field, use the rewrite option and use the taken of your image like

[field_gallery_fid]

and set the Group multiple values like below image

> [image]

2.) In image2 field, use the rewrite option and use the taken of your image like

"[title]" ,"[field_gallery_fid],[field_gallery_fid_1]"

and set the Group multiple values like below image

> [image]

Note: Suppose if you have 10 images, you can repeat the above steps, but if you have **"n"** number of images, then it will not work out for you.

Comment: I have "n" number of images. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter)

> This module add a url formatter for image field. Then you can output image url directly.
>
> Most of the code, maybe more than 90%, is just copy from the drupal core. I think it is stable enough.
>
> I have created a content type, and add an image field instance to it, later I use views to export the data of this content type.And I want to output the data,then I could import it into another drupal 7 site with feeds module. What I need is the URL of the image field, but I could not export the image URL directly. That is why I create this small module.

Comment: Please add some more details about WHY you recommended this module (apart from some module details that Krisna already added, to make it look less like a link-only answer, which often gets deleted by moderation, sinces that's considered as a low quality answer).